# How to see Facebook app by it's Facebook APP_ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've Facebook application's APP_ID, but i don't know how to see this facebook application? i got this APP_ID from my client, i need to work with this app. i want to get photos and comments from this app. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=[YOUR-APP-ID]

Answer (score 1):

you can implement this appid into your code and then run it...
only this way to see your app page....
or you can use this URL https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=[Application ID] but this URL gives you only the app name...

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue but the links you gave above won't work
the problem is that you have to be connected with the very account that created the app in order to be able to see it's page...

Otherwise, it only redirects you on your Facebook account (the last connected indeed) and that's all...

So "up" if anyone's got an idea to retrieve a facebook app with only the app_id and no associated account